# c++11 memcpy data from one int* to another int*

Tags: c++, pointers, memcpy

I have a class:

```
class Kunde{
    char *name;
    char *ort;
    int *alter;
    double umsatz;
    int transaktion;
    int id=0;
    int dummyAlter=20;

    public:
    static int anzahl;

    Kunde(char* n=(char*)"Max Maier", char* o=(char*)"Köln", int *a=&dummyAlter);
    Kunde(const Kunde &k);
    ~Kunde();
    void buy(double u);
    static int getAnzahl();
};
```

In my .cpp-File I have:

```
 Kunde::Kunde(char* n, char* o, int *a)
    {
    name=n;
    ort=o;
    alter=a;
    id=anzahl++;
    umsatz=0;
    transaktion=0;
};
```

and I want to write a copying constructor.

This is achieved by:

```
 Kunde::Kunde(const Kunde &k)
 {
    int lenname=(int)strlen(k.name)+1;
    name=new char[lenname];
    memcpy(name, k.name, lenname);
    int lenort=(int)strlen(k.ort)+1;
    ort=new char[lenort];
    memcpy(ort, k.ort, lenort);

    alter=new int;
    memcpy(alter, k.alter, sizeof(int));

    id=k.id;
    anzahl++;
    umsatz=k.umsatz;
    transaktion=k.transaktion;
}
```

The code compiles just fine but when I execute it, it produces an error where I use memcpy to copy the data from k.alter to alter.

Do you see what is wrong? I tried stfw and rtfm but it seems I'm too stupid to find anything concerning "pure" int*'s instead of int*-Arrays.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: You *do* know that C-style strings contain one more character than reported by `strlen`? The string terminator character `'\0'`. But my biggest question is why don't you use [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string)? Then you wouldn't have to worry about that!

Comment: The `&` in `memcpy(alter, &k.alter, sizeof(int));` doesn't seem right, if you want to copy what `k.alter` points to. Regardless, to copy a single `int`, ordinary assignment would work, you wouldn't need `memcpy` for that one.

Comment: By the way, since you only allocate a single integer, why use a pointer in the first place? And if you want more than one integer, then use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector). The C++ [standard library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp) contains so many things that will make your life as a C++ programmer so much simpler and easier.

Comment: Oh, and you should definitely read about [the rule of three](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29).

Comment: `alter` (which is age) should be declared as a `int`, not as an `int*`. It doesn't make sense to store it at some different location. And you definetly should use std::string for storing all those strings instead of manually managing them as char arrays.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg regarding strlen: yeah, I _should_ know that, I just forgot to add it when I started completely over ;-)

Comment: @Matthias247 regarding the stupid int*: I have to use this one, our prof wants to teach us about deep copies but it seems I didn't get that. The same goes for the char-arrays.

Comment: @Matthias247 - memcpying an int to an int isn't teaching about deep copies. I don't know what it teaches, except maybe how to provide the right arguments to memcpy().  You also didn't write an assignment operator along with the copy constructor and destructor.  Is the teacher teaching you this, that is, you need to supply all 3 functions if you're going to write one of them (the rule of 3)?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie this is what he said today when I asked him if the int* was an error or if he actually wanted to achieve something with that. "This is to teach you about deep copies"... regarding the rule of three: nobody told me about that but I have just looked it up. If I understand that correctly I have to have: a constructor, a copying constructor and a destructor. Correct?

Comment: @Matthias247 - That memcpy() doesn't teach deep copying. If it did, then any 'C' programmer would know what is meant by "deep copying" in terms of C++. Second, if you don't have an assignment operator but have just a user-defined copy ctor, then this code will not work: `Kunde k1; Kunde k2; k1 = k2;` However this code will work `Kunde k1; Kunde k2 = k1;` The two should work, but one won't while the other will. And yes, you need a destructor.

Comment: @Matthias247 - also, your constructor that takes pointers is wrong. You will see it's wrong as soon as you implement your destructor to attempt to free the memory.  In the destructor, you will be attempting to free non-dynamically allocated strings (string literals), causing undefined behavior.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I'm not the question asker ;) But yes, I agree that at least the constructor should take an int instead of an int*. And the constructor should also (deep) copy all values so that they are properly encapsulated by the class and can be safely deleted in the destructor.

Comment: And on more hint: Using memcpy for copying an int is more complicated then necessary. `alter=new int; *alter = *(k->alter);` is easier to understand and does the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some hints from you folks I finally found the problems.

1. **First:** I always tried to save the `char*`s directly (you see this in the constructor) and by that only achieved that I had pointers to my strings.

**Solution:**

```
Kunde::Kunde(char* n, char* o, int a)  
{
    int lenname=(int)strlen(n)+1;
    name=new char[lenname];
    memcpy(name, n, lenname);

    int lenort=(int)strlen(o)+1;
    ort=new char[lenort];
    memcpy(ort, o, lenort);

    alter=new int;
    *alter=a;
    id=anzahl++;
    umsatz=0;
    transaktion=0;
}
```

2. **Second:** I tried to use an `int*` as a parameter for the constructor which a) makes no sense and b) is a royal PITA. After I fixed my parameters I used the construct proposed by @Matthias247 to do the copying of the int-data.

**Solution:**

```
Kunde::Kunde(const Kunde &k) 
{
    int lenname=(int)strlen(k.name)+1;
    name=new char[lenname];
    memcpy(name, k.name, lenname);

    int lenort=(int)strlen(k.ort)+1;
    ort=new char[lenort];
    memcpy(ort, k.ort, lenort);

    alter=new int;
    *alter = *(k.alter);
    id=k.id;
    anzahl++;
    umsatz=k.umsatz;
    transaktion=k.transaktion;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Regarding your problem with the integer pointer, your problem is twofold: First you have the default argument in the constructor which is a pointer to the *address* `20`, not a pointer to the *value* `20`. The second problem is that you use the address-of operator in the `memcpy` call, it will give you the address *of the pointer*, i.e. you have an expression of type `int **`.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the input. I fixed those but it still doesn't work like it should :(